onReorder in framer motion is not working for images
I am using framer-motion library to re-arrange the images of the gallery
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Reorder } from "framer-motion";

const Test = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, pic: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 2, pic: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 3, pic: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" }
  ]);

  return (
   <div className="text-white">
    <p className="text-center text-white">Testing Scroll</p>
    <Reorder.Group
      values={items}
      onReorder={(newOrder) => setItems(newOrder)}
    >
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Reorder.Item key={item.id} value={item}>
          <div>
            <p>Item {item.id}</p>
            <img src={item.pic} alt={`Pic ${item.id}`} />
          </div>
        </Reorder.Item>
      ))}
    </Reorder.Group>
   </div>
  );
};

export default Test;

It does not reorder like that. I tried to do console.log inside the onReorder function and noticed that it is not going inside the onReorder function. Then I changed the value of "pic" of every element
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, pic: "dghge" },
    { id: 2, pic: "htegb" },
    { id: 3, pic: "etyhet" }
  ]);

And after doing this, the reordering works. How can I fix this and what is the reason behind this?

I think your problem is that the img elements handle pointer events by default.
So it doesn't respond to pointer events in the same way as text or other block elements.
To fix this, you can ensure that the img element can participate in pointer events by adding pointer-events: none to the image. This will allow the Reorder.Item to handle the drag for the entire container, including the image.
I have created a stackblitz file to visualize it.
